# How to target multiple tables with different ids in jquery and make them use the same function for drag and drop rows of the data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How to target multiple tables with different ids in jquery and make them use the same function for drag and drop rows of the data table. I have 7 tables with different ids in the same page. To make the rows draggable I am using the below mentioned queries. I want to target all the 7 tables to work in similar way. Thank You

```
"use strict";

const table = document.getElementById('mytable');
const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');


var currRow = null,
    dragElem = null,
    mouseDownX = 0,
    mouseDownY = 0,
    mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0,
    mouseDrag = false;

function init() {
    bindMouse();
}


function bindMouse() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
        if (event.button != 0) return true;

        let target = getTargetRow(event.target);
        if (target) {
            currRow = target;
            addDraggableRow(target);
            currRow.classList.add('is-dragging');


            let coords = getMouseCoords(event);
            mouseDownX = coords.x;
            mouseDownY = coords.y;

            mouseDrag = true;
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        if (!mouseDrag) return;

        let coords = getMouseCoords(event);
        mouseX = coords.x - mouseDownX;
        mouseY = coords.y - mouseDownY;

        moveRow(mouseX, mouseY);
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
        if (!mouseDrag) return;

        currRow.classList.remove('is-dragging');
        table.removeChild(dragElem);

        dragElem = null;
        mouseDrag = false;
    });
}


function swapRow(row, index) {
    let currIndex = Array.from(tbody.children).indexOf(currRow),
        row1 = currIndex > index ? currRow : row,
        row2 = currIndex > index ? row : currRow;

    tbody.insertBefore(row1, row2);
}

function moveRow(x, y) {
    dragElem.style.transform = "translate3d(" + x + "px, " + y + "px, 0)";

    let dPos = dragElem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        currStartY = dPos.y, currEndY = currStartY + dPos.height,
        rows = getRows();

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        let rowElem = rows[i],
            rowSize = rowElem.getBoundingClientRect(),
            rowStartY = rowSize.y, rowEndY = rowStartY + rowSize.height;

        if (currRow !== rowElem && isIntersecting(currStartY, currEndY, rowStartY, rowEndY)) {
            if (Math.abs(currStartY - rowStartY) < rowSize.height / 2)
                swapRow(rowElem, i);
        }
    }
}
function addDraggableRow(target) {
    dragElem = target.cloneNode(true);
    dragElem.classList.add('draggable-table__drag');
    dragElem.style.height = getStyle(target, 'height');
    dragElem.style.background = getStyle(target, 'backgroundColor');
    for (var i = 0; i < target.children.length; i++) {
        let oldTD = target.children[i],
            newTD = dragElem.children[i];
        newTD.style.width = getStyle(oldTD, 'width');
        newTD.style.height = getStyle(oldTD, 'height');
        newTD.style.padding = getStyle(oldTD, 'padding');
        newTD.style.margin = getStyle(oldTD, 'margin');
    }
    table.appendChild(dragElem);
    let tPos = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
        dPos = dragElem.getBoundingClientRect();
    dragElem.style.bottom = ((dPos.y - tPos.y) - tPos.height) + "px";
    dragElem.style.left = "-1px";

    document.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove',
        { view: window, cancelable: true, bubbles: true }
    ));
}
function getRows() {
    return table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
}

function getTargetRow(target) {
    let elemName = target.tagName.toLowerCase();

    if (elemName == 'tr') return target;
    if (elemName == 'td') return target.closest('tr');
}

function getMouseCoords(event) {
    return {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
    };
}

function getStyle(target, styleName) {
    let compStyle = getComputedStyle(target),
        style = compStyle[styleName];

    return style ? style : null;
}

function isIntersecting(min0, max0, min1, max1) {
    return Math.max(min0, max0) >= Math.min(min1, max1) &&
        Math.min(min0, max0) <= Math.max(min1, max1);
}



init();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a static `table` variable, could you add an event to target the table that user is pointing to. Something like, if user hover on table 1, pass it to the function. Because obviously the user only works with 1 table at a time, unless you want user to move rows between tables

Comment: The tables are under different tabs. Yes the user work on one table at a time.

Comment: so you could check for what tab is currently active and then pass it to the `table` variable